# logstash convert time to date time

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I am using logstash to push data from filebeat to elasticsearch. My data has time as `hh:mm:ss a` (05:21:34 AM). I want to add today's date to it.
This is filter of logstash config

```
filter{
    grok{ some grok pattern to get time}
    date {
        locale => "en"
        match => ["time", "hh:mm:ss a"]
        target => "@timestamp"
    }
}
```

But data converted as `2016-01-01T05:21:34.000Z`
How can I change it to `2016-10-14T05:21:34.000Z`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think logstash is smart enough to use the current year (as you're seeing), but it's not defaulting the other fields.

You should make a new field with the full datetime string you want.  Something like this should work between your grok and date:

```
grok { }
mutate {
    add_field => { "datetime" => "%{+YYYY.MM.dd} %{time}" }
}
date { }
```

Be sure to change your date{} pattern to use the new datetime field and its format.  If you don't want the datetime field after date{} is called, you can either use a metadata field instead, or remove_field as part of date{}.

Comment: `add_field => { "datetime" => "%{+YYYY.MM.dd} %{time}" }` whats the difference between adding this statement in grok and mutate?

Comment: add_field (and remove_field) work when the underlying filter succeed.  In your case, you could add it to the grok{}, and it would only create the new [datetime] field if the grok worked.  However, the mutate is using the [time] field, which was just created in that very grok, and that makes me nervous (I've been bitten before with the timing of variables being created by various filters).  It's also more explicit in a separate block.